# Since I've moved to the GNOME Shell, is it safe to remove compiz?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome

I've uninstalled Unity and don't plan on using it again. I know that the GNOME Shell uses Mutter, so is it safe to uninstall Compiz?

Comment: I've uninstalled Compiz back when I switched to running GNOME Shell compiled from `jhbuild` as my primary shell on Ubuntu 10.10 (keeping the older Mutter-based Unity around as a backup). I noticed no problems; in fact, it felt like my system got a lot lighter and speedier after the removal. I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to do this on 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be. To be on the safe side, run a simulation first with

```
sudo apt-get -s remove compiz*
```

`-s` is there for simulation, so that nothing is really removed.

If the list of the 'to be removed' packages looks reasonable, run the above command without `-s`.

Comment: If I do this, it tries to remove ubuntu-desktop... Isn't that, well, my desktop?